# difference between socket failing with EOF and connection reset

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

For testing a networking application, I have written an asio port "proxy": it listens on a socket for the application client activity and sends all incoming packets to another socket where it is listened to by the application server, and back.

Now when either the application or the server disconnect for various reasons, the "proxy" usually gets an EOF but sometimes it receives a "connection reset".

Hence, the question: when does a socket fail with a "connection reset" error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TCP connection is "reset" when the local end attempts to send data to the remote end and the remote end answer with a packet with the `RST` flag set (instead of `ACK`). This almost always happens because the remote end doesn't know about any TCP connection that matches the remote&local addresses and remote&local port numbers. Possible reasons include:

- The remote end has been rebooted
- A state-tracking firewall somewhere in the path has been rebooted/changed/added/removed
- A load balancer has incorrectly directed the TCP connection to a different node than the one it was supposed to go to.
- The remote IP address has changed hands (the new owner doesn't know anything about TCP connections belonging to the old owner).
- The remote end considers that the TCP connection has been closed already (but somehow the local end doesn't agree).

Note that if the remote end answers the initial (`SYN`) packet in a TCP connection with a `RST` packet, it is considered "Connection refused" instead of "Connection reset by peer".

Comment: Some servers also intentionally send `RST` to a misbehaving client to drop the connection immediately because plain `close()` first sends all data pending in the outgoing kernel socket buffer and only then sends `FIN`.

Comment: And if the peer closes the connection while it has pending unread data in its socket receive buffer the connection will also be reset. And it is also possible for the reset to originate locally. There are quite a few scenarios, not just the one you presented here.